# How to send response back to Jmeter over TCP?

Tags: java, tcp, jmeter, messagebroker

How to send response back to Jmeter over TCP?

I've created a TCP sampler in Jmeter which is giving input to my Message broker tool.

I am getting an input message from Jmeter but I cannot send the response back to Jmeter. I am unable to locate the port to send response back to Jmeter.

My question is: Is there a listener port for Jmeter to get the reponse?

I've tried with ports 4445, 1234 and 1099 but that did not work.

Comment: Is there any port in jmeter is waiting for reponse ?

Comment: I think I don't understand the question. Jmeter is used to test web applications, which means It usually works as a client. So, why do you need a port for Jmeter? What you really need is to know the port (and hostname) of the application you are testing with Jmeter.

Comment: What message broker is this? Why aren't you using the JMS samplers?

Comment: we re getting message as input from jmeter to our tool (IBM Message Broker) ... but there is no response data in jmeter.

Comment: Jmeter is waiting for response data...

Comment: We are getting emty in reponse data of Jmeter ? we need to send any response back to jmeter ?

Comment: Yes, Jmeter awaits for an answer from the server it is connected to. So, if Jmeter doesn't receive an answer, I see two options: The server doesn't response or the request from jmeter to server is wrong (could be parameters, IP, port, etc..). First, check out in your server whether it receives the request from Jmeter, then check if server really answers the request.

Comment: yes in server we receiving message from jmeter...

Comment: We are getting sampler test as but Response Data is empty
Sampler Test :
-----------------------
Load time: 81417
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Response code: 200
Response message: OK

Response headers:


SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: windows-1252

Comment: We are getting Response Message as OK but Empty in Response Data...

Comment: Well, everything seems ok. Response code is 200, which is right. I don't know what service does, but empty data could means that server answers nothing. Did you add a Listener in Jmeter to view the results?

Comment: Yes i added a listener in Jmeter

Comment: That listener generated that message... with code 200

Comment: Is it possible your message broker reponds on a different port? Which is why I'm asking why you aren't using the JMS sampler, which would abstract away the TCP details.

Comment: yes it is possible to configure different port to send response... but unable to figure it out... the port which Jmeter wait for response back from server

Comment: We are usign JMS sampler for TCP ... we are getting any reponse data in that sampler.               We are sending response message from Message Broker to 1099 port number

Comment: Thank you very much we resolved that issue... Answer is :  Jmeter wait for the response on the same port which we configured while sending input Message.

Answer (score 0):

We configured Message broker

TCP Server input Node with Port number as : 1111

TCP Server Output node with Port number as : 1111

Jmeter sends message to Message Broker running IPaddress and 1111 port number.

and it wait for the response from Message Broker on the Same port. eg : 1111

Sending   : Jmeter (196.35.22.33:1111) ---> (TCP Server input node:1111)Message Broker

Receiving : Message Broker (TCP Server output node: 1111)---> Jmeter(196.35.22.33:1111)

Note: 196.35.22.33 is just an example

Thank you for your suggestions made me think different